# Scheduled Firebase cloud functions timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am getting `Cloud Function finished with status: 'timeout'"` error when running scheduled cloud function on Firebase. Probably I am not finishing it properly, but I cannot find the issue, would really appreciate any help.

So, I have to perform two https request in a sequence, I am using promises for it. In the end, I am getting the result, it works, but I don't want to have timeouts, as it is running periodically.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const https = require('https');

exports.somePeriodicRequest = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('40 */11 * * *')
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const firstRequest = https.request(firstRequestOptions, (firstRequestResult) => {
        firstRequestResult.on('data', (response) => {
          var data = JSON.parse(response);

          resolve(data.property);
        });
      });

      firstRequestRequest.on('error', (e) => {
        functions.logger.error(e);

        reject();
      });

      firstRequestRequest.write(firstRequestBody);
      firstRequestRequest.end();
    }).then((property) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const secondRequest = https.request(secondRequestOptions, (secondRequestResult) => {
          secondRequestResult.on('data', (response) => {
            resolve();
          });
        });

        secondRequestRequest.on('error', (e) => {
          functions.logger.error(e);

          reject();
        });

        secondRequestRequest.write(property);
        secondRequestRequest.end();
      });
    });
  });
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This will probably be much easier if you pick an API for your requests that uses async/await syntax instead of creating new promise objects.  This will make your code easier to read and write.  In modern javascript and APIs, it's never really a good idea to `new Promise`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to @doug-stevenson, I replaced promises with [axios http client](https://axios-http.com) and now it works without any timeouts.

Example:

```
exports.extendEvaluationTokenLife = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('every 5 minutes')
  .retryConfig({
    retryCount: 3,
    maxBackoffDuration: '120s',
    maxRetryDuration: '300s',
    minBackoffDuration: '5s'
  })
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    await axios({
      method: 'put',
      url: 'https://some.url/api/something/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/json"
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
      if (error.response) {
        // Request made and server responded
        functions.logger.error(error.response.data);
        functions.logger.error(error.response.status);
        functions.logger.error(error.response.headers);
      } else if (error.request) {
        // The request was made but no response was received
        functions.logger.error(error.request);
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
        functions.logger.error('Error', error.message);
      }
    });

    return null;
  });
```